# Handling unregistered Website Visitors [php]

Tags: php, user-management

I am  making a hotels booking website. I need to save visited hotels, searches and interests of every visitor, that is registered or unregistered.

Now for registered user's it's easy, I can save them in Session variable with respect to their userId and retrieve too, but for unregistered users, what should I do?

Some people suggest, make a new user in Database for every visitor and save their id in cookies. Now this is a valid solution but, if a user deletes his cookies and is using a proxy, he can have multiple accounts easily.

Kindly guide me to a secure and authentic way.

Comment: Do they have to be connected to a given user? How do unregistered user `A` differ from unregistered user `B` or even registered user `D`?

Comment: You are pretty much confined to cookies or an I.P. address or a combination of the two.  Create a lookup table with a unique identifier for guests and key it to either a cookie value and/or I.P. address.  A match on either one will identify a returning guest.

Comment: @Jite I have to track their bookings too.
so they need to be. PS might be possible in future, I'm asked to put in a new feature of providing deals on visitors with most bookings

Comment: @AkinWilliams I mentioned that case in my question, deleting cookies and using proxy can produce the duplication.

Comment: @Deptikon - true. you may look into detecting whether the user is behind a proxy.